# JQuery draggable element not moving

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a simple draggable example, which is not working. Draggable element (div with green border) is not moving when I try to move it with the mouse.

My code for dragging:

```
  $("#divDraggable").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone'

  });
```

I just want to copy element into another (larger) element. If it's not dropped, return it to it's initial position. Why it's not working?

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("#divDraggable").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone'
    
  });



  
  
  $("#divDroppable").droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        debugger;
        var droppable = $(this);
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);        
    }
    
    
  });

  
  
})
```

```css
#divDroppable{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#divDraggable{
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://test73.webo.hosting/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://test73.webo.hosting/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<link href="https://test73.webo.hosting/Styles/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="divDroppable" class="draggable"></div>
<div id="divDraggable"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/4hzcq0q5/

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("#divDraggable").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone',
  });
  
  $("#divDroppable").droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var droppable = $(this);
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);        
    }   
  });  
})
```

```css
#divDroppable{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#divDraggable{
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="divDroppable" ></div>
<div id="divDraggable" class="draggable">

</div>
```

Issue was with you class `class="draggable"` added to **dropped div** instead of **draggable div**.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with `helper` attribute in draggable. Please check this fiddle, i remove helper property and its work https://jsfiddle.net/x6hdan8L/1/

Comment: The OP says they want to copy the element rather than move it, they probably do want `helper: 'clone'`  Is maybe the `accept` the problem?

Comment: In your fiddle I don't see element dragging? It appears when mouse button is released.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax was wrong. It should be like this:

```
$("#divDraggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone'

  });
```

Working example:

[draggable](https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/xLLrQL?editors=1010)

Comment: This is the solution you are looking for??? But this solution is also not moving the green div.

Comment: @Shiladitya - I've pasted link to working example. In this example, syntax is like my original question. Although, there is some more code. I don't understand why it's working and on the example above it's not working.